# How i can see if this function is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need see if this function is decreasing in the interval $[1,\infty)$

I know a function is decreasing when his derivative is minor or equal to $0$.

My function:

\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3}}\\
f'(x)&=\frac{x^{3}\cos(x)-3x^{2}\sin(x)}{x^{6}}\end{align}

Then $$f'(x)\leq0\Leftrightarrow x^{3}\cos(x)-3x^{2}\sin(x)\leq0\Leftrightarrow x\cos(x)-3\sin(x)\leq0$$

I dont know how I can solve that equation, can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for a derivative. The function has an alternating sign because of the sine, then it cannot be monotonic.

Comment: Yves Daoust is right. If you want to be convinced once you have computed you rderivative, you don not need to "solve" the inequality. It suffices to put in evidence the fact that $f'(\pi)<0$ whereas $f'(3\pi/2)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is no need to even investigate the derivative, let us show that it takes both signs.

In
$$g(x):=x\cos x-3\sin x,$$ the second term is at most $3$ in absolute value, while the first can reach $\pm x$. So, let us pick values such that $x>3$ and $\cos x=\pm1$ (they do exist), and we are done.

For instance,

$$g(2\pi)=2\pi,\\g(3\pi)=-3\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Take a look at the values for $x$ for which $\sin x = \pm 1$, especially the sign of the function at those values.

Answer (score 0):

Sine function will always be wavy when mutiplied or divided by monotonic functions.

Infinite number of real roots exist for zero first derivative as

$$ \frac{\sin x}{x^2} =  \frac{\cos x }{2x} $$

It need not be actually solved. Intersection of graph will suffice. Verify second derivative alternates in sign.

Its envelopes decrease or increase monotonically.